# JQuery: don't focus out when clicking on something

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div, #someDiv, on which I have some jQuery code to execute when focused on, and when focused out. But I want to achieve an action in which, if a certain other div is clicked on when div #1 is focused on, that focus remains on the div:

```
$(document).on("focus", "#someDiv", function() {

// Some code here to execute

}).on("focusout", "#someDiv", function() {

if (#someDiv2 was clicked on) { // DON'T focus out from #someDiv }


});
```

...however the issue is that jQuery is unable to distinguish that during the focus out, a click was made. How can I achieve this effect?

EDIT: Basically the idea I am trying to implement is a mock web-app in which you can customize a certain kind of div when it has focus, and upon that, an "options" div appears. I don't want the options bar to disappear when it is clicked, as otherwise none of the "options" can be chosen.

Comment: The click event happens after the blur event in Chrome, so you're going to have to monitor the click event and the blur event and correlate those two somehow later on.

Comment: you should delayed your logic to check wich element was clicked. Could you provide a jsFiddle?

Comment: Cannot you provide a simple jsfiddle which replicates your issue? Should be quite easy to find a workaround

Answer (score 0):

One half baked solution is to simply monitor the time for click / blur and correlate the two:

http://jsfiddle.net/ztA5F/

```
var lastBlur = new Date().getTime();
$("html").on("click", function() {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    console.log(lastBlur);
    console.log(now);
    if (lastBlur >= (new Date().getTime() - 500))
        $("#input").focus();
    console.log("click");
});

$("#input").on("blur", function() {
    lastBlur = new Date().getTime();
    console.log("blur");
});
```

Comment: I see, so the only way to detect if a click at this point is to measure the "duration" between the click and the blur?

Comment: There may be other ways, this is just the obvious one that I see.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain I totally understand what you're after, but maybe this will be helpful:

```
var lastID;
$(document).on('click focus', function (e) {
    var id = $(e.target).attr('id');
    if (id === 'someDiv2' && lastID === 'someDiv') {
        $('#someDiv').trigger('focus');     
    }
    lastID = id; 
});
```